# how to center a grid container using align-content?

Tags: css

How to center a grid container ?
I'm trying to center the grid (with all the images) horizontally and vertically in the middle of the page.
I've tried to use align-content:center with a height but it doesn't work.
It works only with justify-content: center.
Thanks.

```
.gallery {
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 300px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center; 
  height: 100vh;

}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      
      <img src="1.jpeg" class="img img_1" />
      
      <img src="2.jpeg" class="img img_2" />
      
      <img src="3.jpeg" class="img img_3" />
      
      <img src="4.jpeg" class="img img_4" />
      
      <img src="5.jpeg" class="img img_5" />
      
      <img src="6.jpeg" class="img img_6" />
      
      <img src="7.jpeg" class="img img_7" />
      
      <img src="8.jpeg" class="img img_8" />
      
      <img src="9.jpeg" class="img img_9" />
      
      <img src="10.jpeg" class="img img_10" />
      
      <img src="1.jpeg" class="img img_11" />
      
      <img src="1.jpeg" class="img img_12" />
      
        

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: You have set each row to 300px but the height of the grid element to 100vh which is probably less than all the rows. Which do you want?

Comment: works just fine for me